# "Could not load source layer for MASK: invalid value" error when iterating over features in polygon layer and clipping raster by mask layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, clip, iterator, qgsfeaturerequest

I have just started using PyQGIS and need to loop over parcels in a vector layer to clip a raster layer.

For each parcel, I want to generate a *.tif* file with the `feature.id()` in the filename. I will also be saving the attributes in a separate *.csv/.txt* file by the same name. Because of this, I can't run the script using the iterator in the GUI.

This is what I have come up with thus far:

```py
raster = 'C:/Datasets/orthophotos/OMWRGB21VL_K14_K15/OMWRGB21_VL_K14_K15.tif'
Lbgbrprc = 'C:/Datasets/Landbouwgebruikspercelen/Landbouwgebruikspercelen_2020/Shapefile/Lbgbrprc20_SintNiklaas.shp'
Lbgbrprc = QgsVectorLayer(Lbgbrprc, 'landbouw', 'ogr')

params = {
    'ALPHA_BAND' : False,
    'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True,
    'DATA_TYPE' : 0,
    'EXTRA' : '',
    'INPUT' : raster,
    'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False,
    'MULTITHREADING' : False,
    'NODATA' : None,
    'OPTIONS' : '',
    'SET_RESOLUTION' : False,
    'SOURCE_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31370'),
    'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31370'),
    'X_RESOLUTION' : None,
    'Y_RESOLUTION' : None
}

request = QgsFeatureRequest()
for feature in Lbgbrprc.getFeatures(request):
    if int(feature.id()) < 5:
        print(type(feature)) # <class 'qgis._core.QgsFeature'>
        params['MASK'] = feature
        params['OUTPUT'] = 'C:/Output/ortho_Lbgbrprc/{}.tif'.format(feature.id())
        
        processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", params)
```

This is the error I get:

> ```py
> Could not load source layer for MASK: invalid value
> ```

I think the issue is that the 'MASK' parameter needs to be a `QgsVectorLayer` not a `QgsFeature`, which is what "feature" is now. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the type of Mask layer should be a `[vector: polygon]` i.e. `QgsVectorLayer`, [see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#clip-raster-by-mask-layer).

Also, visible via `processing.algorithmHelp("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer")`:

```
...
MASK: Mask layer

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource

    Accepted data types:
        - str: layer ID
        - str: layer name
        - str: layer source
        - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition
        - QgsProperty
        - QgsVectorLayer
...
```

So, one shall modify this parameter:

```py
params['MASK'] = feature
```

as was also mentioned by @MrXsquared to this:

```py
params['MASK'] = Lbgbrprc.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(feature.id()))
```

---

Another option, that can be less resource-consuming, utilizes the [`QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition.html) class.

*Input:*

[image: input]

```py
from os.path import abspath
from qgis import processing
from qgis.core import QgsProject

project_path = abspath('C:/Users/Taras/Downloads/GIS data/')

vector_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Lbgbrprc21_selection')[0]
raster_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OMWRGB14VL_K338z')[0]

params = {
    'ALPHA_BAND' : False,
    'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True,
    'DATA_TYPE' : 0,
    'EXTRA' : '',
    'INPUT' : raster_layer,
    'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False,
    'MULTITHREADING' : False,
    'NODATA' : None,
    'OPTIONS' : '',
    'SET_RESOLUTION' : False,
    'SOURCE_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31370'),
    'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31370'),
    'X_RESOLUTION' : None,
    'Y_RESOLUTION' : None
}

for feature in vector_layer.getFeatures():
    if int(feature.id()) < 5:
        vector_layer.select(feature.id())
        params['MASK'] = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(vector_layer.id(), True)
        params['OUTPUT'] = f"{project_path}/{feature.id()}.tif"
        processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", params)
        vector_layer.removeSelection()
```

*Outputs:*

[image: outputs]

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html)
- [Running PyQGIS algorithm on selected features in layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311336/running-pyqgis-algorithm-on-selected-features-in-layer)

Comment: Thank you so much! The first solution works.
For the second approach, I get the error "Could not load source layer for MASK: landbouw_53536513_e03e_4466_bf80_58088bb4ac38 not found"

Comment: I just tested this with `"native:countpointsinpolygon"` and it works, with no errors. Maybe you can share a sample of your data?

Comment: I tried with a different polygon layer, I still get the same error. For now, I am working with the first solution, so my problem is fixed. Maybe when I learn more about pyQGIS, I will be able to see why I get that error. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: But can you share a sample of your data ? It shall work though. Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have uploaded a tiff file and a selection of the parcels to https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao2sPEougj-phzJjBa_F0crYACdM?e=U4bnlM

Comment: Please, do not forget to send your shapefile properly ;-)

Comment: my apologies! I've added the other files