# TypeError when extracting vertices based on selection in QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, vertices, typeerror, qgsvectorlayer

I want to extract 70% of the vertices based on a selection but I get the following error code:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
> TypeError: QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
>   overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
>   overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
> ```

I get the error when I use the code below. I can see in my active layer that the selection works.

```py
import os
import shutil
import time

t_begin = time.localtime()
print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', t_begin))

particulier = "C:/Users/laptop Innoforte 1/Innoforte/Innoforte Druten - Documenten/9. ICT/QGIS projecten/GOV haalbaarheidsstudie v1/70_particulier"

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression("Wtype != 'Appartement' and Wtype != 'Utiliteit' and cooperatie is not 2")

processing.run("native:randomextract", {
'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer, selectedFeaturesOnly=True,
featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
'METHOD': 0, 'NUMBER': 70, 'OUTPUT': particulier})

iface.addVectorLayer(particulier, '', 'ogr')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could get the same error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
> TypeError: QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
>   overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
>   overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
> ```

To overcome this `TypeError`, please modify this part of the code:

```py
processing.run("native:randomextract", {
    'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(
                layer,
                selectedFeaturesOnly=True,
                featureLimit=-1,
                geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
    'METHOD':0,
    'NUMBER':70,
    'OUTPUT':particulier
    })
```

enhancing it with [`layer.id()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a4357e72f2c4a36d71225c286e3ef95ab), like this:

```py
processing.run("native:randomextract", {
    'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(
                layer.id(),
                selectedFeaturesOnly=True,
                featureLimit=-1,
                geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
    'METHOD':0,
    'NUMBER':70,
    'OUTPUT':particulier
    })
```

or using the [`layer.name()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a36c2af8daef522a221d7ee67b257b057).

The [`QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition.html#a87bbbc3fc237c3cc0abc10902b04aba0) class requires the source to be a `QString` or a `QgsProperty`:

> Usually a static property set to a source layer's ID or file name.

---

**References:**

- [Running PyQGIS algorithm on selected features in layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311336/running-pyqgis-algorithm-on-selected-features-in-layer)

Answer (score 4):

QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition wants the layer.id():

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", 
    {'INPUT':layer,'EXPRESSION':' id%2=0 ','METHOD':0})

print(f"Total feature count: {layer.featureCount()}")
print(f"Selected features: {layer.selectedFeatureCount()}")


processing.runAndLoadResults("native:randomextract", {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id()
, selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
'METHOD':1,'NUMBER':100,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

extracted = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Extracted (random)")[0]

print(f"Extracted features: {extracted.featureCount()}")
```

[image]