# Converting QGIS Algorithm from history to a plugin / tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Rather than going through the process of creating a plugin is there a way to take algorithms from the history and put them together to create a quick tool like in ArcMap?

For example I have

```
processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('_DCDB_July2017_a5475545_fb58_4c0a_b257_588c1ea8c0d4', True),'DISTANCE':1000,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':False,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

and

```
processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':'D:/Cadastre/_DCDB_July2017.tab','PREDICATE':[0],'INTERSECT':'Polygon?crs=EPSG:28355&field=OBJECTID:integer&field=LOT:string(5)&field=PLAN:string(10)&field=LOTPLAN:string(15)&field=SEG_NUM:integer&field=PAR_NUM:integer&field=SEGPAR:integer&field=PAR_IND:integer&field=LOT_AREA:double&field=EXCL_AREA:double&field=LOT_VOLUME:double&field=SURV_IND:string(1)&field=TENURE:string(40)&field=PRC:integer&field=PARISH:string(20)&field=COUNTY:string(16)&field=LAC:integer&field=SHIRE_NAME:string(40)&field=FEAT_NAME:string(60)&field=ALIAS_NAME:string(254)&field=LOC:integer&field=LOCALITY:string(30)&field=PARCEL_TYP:string(24)&field=COVER_TYP:string(10)&field=ACC_CODE:string(40)&field=CA_AREA_SQM:double&field=O_SHAPE_AREA:double&field=O_SHAPE_LEN:double&field=Shape_Length:double&field=Shape_Area:double&uid={61b8a064-9170-42ea-b1bd-117e1d914dfb}','METHOD':0})
```

I want to be able to select a block, click on the button and enter in the buffer distance and it should add a layer with this.

In graphical modeller I can't get it to only buffer on a selection -otherwise this would have been a possible solution.

--- Update based on [How to run QGIS algorithms with selected features?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311149/how-to-run-qgis-algorithms-with-selected-features) I tried the following

```
import processing
input_vlayer = 'D:\Cadastre\_DCDB_July2017.tab'
intersect_vlayer = 'Some path'

input_vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(input_vlayer,  'input_vlayer', 'ogr')
intersect_vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(intersect_vlayer,  
                                       'intersect_vlayer', 'ogr')


for i in range(5):

    # Select the features
    input_vlayer.select(i)
    # Set input params
    params = {'INPUT':input_vlayer,'DISTANCE':1000,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':False,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
    result = processing.run("native:buffer", params)
```

But it runs on the whole dataset.

Comment: Also tried

    # Select the features
    input_vlayer.select(i)
    input_vlayer = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(input_vlayer.id(), True)
    # Set input params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use extract by location instead of select and you should be good with the modeller.

Comment: The following worked -had to save to disk...           Buffer_result = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.source(), True),'DISTANCE':buffer,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':False,'OUTPUT':'D:/buffer.tab'})
            iLayer=QgsVectorLayer(Buffer_result['OUTPUT'],'Buffer','ogr')
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(iLayer)

Comment: Intersect_result = processing.run("native:extractbylocation", { 'INPUT' : 'C:/resources/rivers.shp', 'INTERSECT' : 'D:/buffer.tab', 'OUTPUT' : 'D:/intersect.tab', 'PREDICATE' : [0] })
            iLayer=QgsVectorLayer(Intersect_result['OUTPUT'],'Intersect Result','ogr')
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(iLayer)